# insert a line several places below or above certain pattern

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have this text:

```
bar


eor
mv foo bar
```

I want to insert a line 2 or 3 lines above mv because eor repeats along the file and I just need to add the line once.

I tried this:

```
sed -i '/mv/2i \this' file
```

I tried some awk variations like:

```
awk '/mv/ { print; print "new line"; previous }2'
```

none of these work. Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: Does the mv line only appear once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if (/mv/) tgt=NR-2; next} FNR==tgt{print "new stuff"} 1' file file
bar

new stuff

eor
mv foo bar
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e ':a;N;s/\n/&/2;Ta;/\nmv[^\n]*$/i\new stuff' -e 'P;D' file
```

Open a running window of 3 lines throughout the length of the file and when the current start of line matches `mv`, insert the text `new stuff`, otherwise print/delete the first line of the window and repeat.